# Exporting references to MS Word with bibtex4word

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, msword, jabref

Fairly new to LaTeX, not good in MS Word, and this is my first question on this forum.

I have written a manuscript in LaTeX using BibLaTeX with JabRef and now have no other option but to export to MS Word. For the body, I found LaTeX2RTF to work, although it could not handle citations and left out the bibliography. I have downloaded and installed bibtex4word. My question is regarding the citation style. In the header for the original LaTeX file, I spent considerable effort to get the reference style tweaked. How can I do that with bibtex4word?
My original header in LaTeX

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}

    \usepackage[authordate-trad, giveninits, uniquename=mininit, maxcitenames=2, url=false,  backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
    \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}
    \AtEveryBibitem{%
        \ifentrytype{online}
        {}
        {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issn}}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
    \DeclareSourcemap{
        \maps[datatype=biblatex]{
            \map{
                \step[fieldsource=issue, match=\regexp{\A(\d+)\Z}, final]
                \step[fieldset=number, fieldvalue={$1$}]
                \step[fieldset=issue, null]
            }
        }
    }

    \makeatletter
    \renewbibmacro*{journal+issue+year+pages}{%
        \iftoggle{cms@numbermonth}{}{\clearfield{month}}%
        \usebibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}%
        \setunit{\,}%
        \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{issue}\AND\iffieldundef{month}
            \AND\iffieldundef{number}}%
        {\setunit{\addcolon\,}}%<--- no conditional any more here
        {\printtext[parens]{%  Perhaps if it's wrong use magazine subtype?
                \iffieldundef{issue}
                {\usebibmacro{date}%
                    \printfield{number}}%
                {\printfield{issue}%
                    \setunit{\,}%
                    \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}%
            \setunit{\addcolon\,}}
        \printfield{pages}}

    \renewbibmacro*{periodical+issue+year+pages}{%
        \iftoggle{cms@numbermonth}{}{\clearfield{month}}%
        \usebibmacro{cperiodical+ser+vol+num}%
        \setunit{\,}%
        \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{issue}\AND\iffieldundef{month}
            \AND\iffieldundef{number}}%
        {\setunit{\addcolon\,}}%<--- no conditional any more here
        {\printtext[parens]{%
                \iffieldundef{issue}
                {\usebibmacro{date}%
                    \printfield{number}}%
                {\printfield{issue}%
                    \setunit{\,}%
                    \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}%
            \setunit{\addcolon\,}}
        \printfield{pages}}
    \makeatother


    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs, caption} 
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[displaymath, mathlines]{lineno}
    \usepackage{authblk}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
    \providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords: }} #1}
    \addbibresource{_mysources_.bib}

    %opening
    \title{My nice title}
    \author[1]{Me I}
    \author[2]{Someone Else}
    \author[1]{Third Author}
    \affil[1]{University of Somewhere, Department of Something}
    \affil[2]{Other University}
    \date{} %% if you don't need date to appear
    \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
    \renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\center\uppercase}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries} % Do not use this layer for Some Journal
    \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries}
    \titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\bfseries} % Do not use this layer for Some Journal

    \begin{document}
    %\linenumbers %Comment out to use LaTeX2RTF
    \maketitle
    \begin{doublespace}

    %\begin{abstract} %TODO Complete the formatting for abstract or use abstract as a section unto itself
    %Abstract goes here
    %\end{abstract}

    \section{Abstract}
    My abstract text goes here.

    \keywords{keyword1, keyword2}

    \section{Introduction}

    Some introduction \parencite{example2017}.

    \section{Conclusions}

    Some smart ending.

    \printbibliography
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{document}
```

Suppose I have my JabRef database with an entry.

```
    @Article{example2017,
      author   = {First Last1 and Second Last2 and Third Last3},
      title    = {How to do something useful with word – A systems study},
      year     = {2017},
      volume   = {35},
      number   = {1},
      pages    = {679 - 689},
      issn     = {iiss-ssnn},
      doi      = {vv.xxxx/j.biombioe.2017.01.xxx},
      url      = {http://www.pseudoscience.com/science/article/yyy/xxxxx},
      file     = {:C\:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\example2017.pdf:PDF},
      journal  = {Name of Journal},
      keywords = {keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5, keyword6 },
      review   = {},
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using JabRef already, you can simply use the builtin export functionality for Office 2007 xml format, that is the format where Microsoft stores it bibliography information.

1. Export (selected) entries in JabRef and choose Office 2007 xml format
2. Open Word, click on the References Tab
3. Click on Manage sources -> Browse -> Open the exported XML File (or better copy it directly to the location under browse)
4. All entries are then available in the MS bibliography database

A list of all field mappings between bibtex/biblatex and MS-Office for the export is listed here in JabRef: [Bibtex-MSOffice Field mapping](http://help.jabref.org/en/MsOfficeBibFieldMapping)

The only problem in the export could be when you have a "company" as author. That would be simply exported as author and not in the company field. 
If you encounter any problems, please let me know, because some time ago I worked at the export functionality.

Comment: This works (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-bibliography-17686589-4824-4940-9c69-342c289fa2a5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) helped get things into MS Word. In MS Word I chose Chicago style as this best fits my formatting from the LaTeX heading. Is there a way to write a style for bibtex4word or in MS Word to get the reference style to what I could do in LaTeX or is this a matter of manual labour only?

Comment: I am currently in the process of going through each entry in the MS Word document to find errors. The Pubstate field appears not to copy over (currently I am typing them in) In JabRef certain fields are by default lower case (except first letter), with upper case noted with {}. This does not export as such, so I get {ASTM I}nter...  or Name Of Article when I should get ASTM Inter.. or Name of article.   - I will post other errors as I come across them.

Comment: The number field does not export from JabRef to MS Word

Comment: I just fixed the exporting of the number. The pubstate has no corresponding xml field, so it gets exported as BITEX_Pubstate.
I updated the help accordingly. 
The new version can be found here: https://builds.jabref.org/officeXML/

To your other question: The Office styles are also xsl/xml based:
You can modify them/create your own:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/office/jj851016.aspx